# Are there other size tires that could replace the P185/60/R16 on my Toyota Yaris?

Tags: toyota, yaris

I own a 2017 Yaris is, tire size is a new one, P185/60/R16. Replacing directly from Toyota will cost $170 per tire. Similar tires go for ~$50. Any other size that will work here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You are asking about a different size to what end? Is it cost alone? You can fit other sizes, but really, you should just look at different brands of the same size. It's the easiest and cheapest if you are only looking to get something which fits your budget better.

Comment: Paul's right - different size tyres will result in the speedo reading differently because the total diameter of the wheel will be different. Not sure if that's legal or not in America, but at the very least, it can be a nightmare when making sure you aren't speeding.

Comment: @MRichards - There's no issue in the States using different sized tires ... one look at off road mudder trucks and you'd have no doubt in your mind you can do it. People would go nutz if they were forced to *only* use what came stock on the vehicle ;-)

Comment: why do you need to change the tire so soon?

Comment: Unless you are replacing all 4 tires, I would recommend an exact replacement to keep the tires a matching set.

Comment: Look on the Tire Rack site.

Comment: this is indeed an odd size, tire rack only has one option (toyo @ $110 ).  I really doubt you will find any 16 inch tire for $50

Comment: FWIW if you want to buy new wheels I think you can run 175/65R15 (OEM on base model yaris), then you have many more options including getting into the $50 neighborhood.  Note in some cases models with larger wheels have larger brakes and can not use base size wheels.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize options:

**1. Same size tire, different brand**

- Easiest option, should create little to no issues.
- Ideally change all four tires at once, but if you absolutely can't do that, change either the front pair or rear pair together.
- Pay attention to things like load and speed ratings to make sure you have equivalent capability on the new tires as you did on the stock ones.

**2. Same tire diameter, different tire size, different rim size**

- This can be a good option if you want to expand your tire size selection to include cheaper models. (15" tires for example, are often cheaper than the equivalent diameter 16" tire)
- As mentioned in comments above, make absolutely sure that your new rims have clearance for the brakes and suspension parts, especially if you are going with a smaller diameter rim.
- Be aware that increasing or decreasing your section width (distance from rim to outside edge of tire), is going to affect the handling of the vehicle one way or another.
- The additional cost of new rims on top of new tires will probably outweigh the cost benefit of being able to use cheaper tires, at least in the immediate time frame.

**3. Different tire diameter than stock**

- This is the least ideal option. Especially with smaller vehicles, changing the tire size can dramatically change handling, and engine performance due to the drivetrain gearing no longer being correct for the tire diameter.
- Larger tires can increase unsprung weight, which will affect braking and overall handling. Changes in section height again will also affect handling.
- Changing to larger tires without adjusting drivetrain gears will often cause the displayed speed on the speedometer to be lower than the actual speed of the vehicle. You will need to use a phone or a gps device to display your actual speed (or permanently adjust the cars display speed if that is an option)
- With larger tires, you are very likely to encounter clearance issues, and possibly even some rubbing on the fender sidewall when suspension is compressed or when front wheels are turned all the way in either direction. This may require serious modifications to the suspension, and will probably exceed the value benefit of using different size tires.
- Changing tire size will likely require an alignment job. In extreme cases, you may no longer be able to properly align suspension components within spec.
- Overall advantages are fewer with smaller cars. Tire size is usually increased to improve ground clearance, but the risks may outweigh the benefits on smaller vehicles.